# Avatar not wooking when i use with Mui selectTag

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I use avatar in MUI to display images in tagSelect, but it isn't working.

[image: Example of selectbox avatar not working]

```
<FormControl sx={{ width: "27.5rem" }}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
      id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
      multiple={true}
      value={valueTag}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
      renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
        {listFoodSelectbox.map((item) => (
          <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.name}>
              <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                  {/* <Avatar url="/static/logo7.png" alt="food" /> */}
                  <Avatar url={item.image} alt="food" />
              </Stack>

              <Checkbox checked={valueTag.indexOf(item.name) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Avatar url={item.image} alt="food" />
```

to `<Avatar src={item.image} alt="food" />`

tôi đã nhầm lẫn src thành url

sorry for my stupid